# Use Websocket with Google Compute Engine, HTTP(S) Load balancer

Tags: spring-boot, websocket, load-balancing, google-compute-engine, spring-websocket

I'm trying to use Websocket with my spring boot app powered by GCE.

I'm using the same websocket code than => https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-websocket-jetty

I'm using HTTPS load balancing and it's seems the load balancer does not like the https because it work on HTTP but not on HTTPS.

You can try my snake test game here (In simple HTTP) =>  http://www.writecontrol.fr/websocket/snake.html

There is an error if you test the same URL with HTTPS =>  https://www.writecontrol.fr/websocket/snake.html

I'm using ingress load balancer extensions/v1beta1

The SSL is based on a "secret tls" => https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/enabling-ssl

So there is SSL between client and HTTPS load balancer, but not between load balancer and application instances

Logs into the application instance seems correct (No Exception) :

2017-12-20 20:07:04.986  INFO 5 --- [tp1875108260-24] monitoring                               : remoteAddr = 10.240.0.4, forwardedFor = 176.170.4.209, 35.190.37.177, request = /websocket/snake/info GET: 3 ms, 0 Ko

This is the log in GCE load balancing logging

```
 httpRequest: {
  remoteIp: "176.170.4.209"   
  requestMethod: "GET"   
  requestSize: "1940"   
  requestUrl: "https://www.writecontrol.fr/websocket/snake/370/5ho3g2ed/websocket"   
  responseSize: "414"   
  serverIp: "10.240.0.2"   
  status: 501   
  userAgent: "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36"   
 }
 insertId: "148f3zg42bp37f"  
 jsonPayload: {
  @type: "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.loadbalancing.type.LoadBalancerLogEntry"   
  statusDetails: "websocket_handshake_failed"   
 }
 logName: "projects/writecontrol-1055/logs/requests"  
 receiveTimestamp: "2017-12-20T18:47:23.815984409Z"  
 resource: {
  labels: {
   backend_service_name: ""    
   forwarding_rule_name: "k8s-fws-default-gateway-preprod-ingress--69a82c51321bbe98"    
   project_id: "writecontrol-1055"    
   target_proxy_name: "k8s-tps-default-gateway-preprod-ingress--69a82c51321bbe98"    
   url_map_name: "k8s-um-default-gateway-preprod-ingress--69a82c51321bbe98"    
   zone: "global"    
  }
  type: "http_load_balancer"   
 }
 severity: "WARNING"  
 timestamp: "2017-12-20T18:47:22.935633707Z"  
 trace: "projects/writecontrol-1055/traces/79e8cc41423a19b5a52f6c432257a7d6"
```

Do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: Which [certificate](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/ssl-certificates) are you using on the backend?

Comment: Hey thank you ! No ssl between ingress and backend. No certificates

Comment: Is the backend configured for HTTP on the websocket connection, or is it expecting HTTPS?

Comment: The backend is configured for HTTP. If you test http://www.writecontrol.fr/websocket/snake.html (without https) you can see the snake game working

Comment: Indeed I did see that it works; it's possible that your backend (or the GCLB) is misconfigured such that the backend expects HTTPS for the websocket but is getting HTTP (or vice versa). Have you tried using the non-beta extension?

Comment: I followed the documentation to set my ingress configuration
https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer

Do you have a documentation about the non beta extension ? What can i put instead ?

Comment: You said `The SSL is based on a "secret tls" => https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/enabling-ssl` and then `So there is SSL between client and HTTPS load balancer, but not between load balancer and application instances` -- the first link involves setting up TLS on the backend. Thus, try removing the TLS on the backend.

Comment: Perhaps i'm wrong but create a "secret tls" does not involve to have TLS on the backend.

This is the ingress configuration to put SSL on ingress but not on the backend.


`apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: gateway-prod3-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: gateway-prod3-static-ip
spec:
  tls:
  - secretName: gateway-prod-secret-2017-with-ca
  backend:
    serviceName: gateway-prod3
    servicePort: 80`

The relative documentation
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#tls

Comment: You're doing TLS/SSL on the backend with this. The TLS is going to be handled entirely by GCLB, so remove it from Kubernetes.

Comment: I'm not doing TLS/SSL on the backend. You can access to the backend without SSL.

try this.  http://writecontrol.fr/websocket/snake.html

Comment: That one works, yes, but you have another one which the link you provided clear says is using TLS: `spec: tls: - secretName: gateway-prod-secret-2017-with-ca`